# How to solve problem with column name in Active Record Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

I have a black list of email domains in db (table `black_list_domains` with fields `id` and `domain`) and I need to validate user's email address while registration.

The validation must add error if user's email matches pattern `'%@%domain'`.

So, working mysql-query is:

```
SELECT * FROM `black_list_domains` WHERE '$email' LIKE CONCAT('%@%', domain)"
```

But when I try to make this checking in my Validator's class with Active Record:

```
BlackListDomains::find()->where(['like', $email, new \yii\db\Expression("CONCAT('%@%', domain)")])->exists();
```

it returns a MySQL error `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'test@test.test' in 'where clause'` (`test@test.test` is user's email address).

I can make a correct query with `createCommand`:

```
\Yii::$app->db->createCommand("SELECT * FROM `black_list_domains` WHERE '$email' LIKE CONCAT('%@%', domain)")->queryAll();
```

But I think it is possible to make this with Active Record. Or not?

Comment: You can look at sql, that AR generated for MySQL like so: 
```$query = new Books::find()->where('author=2');
echo $query->createCommand()->sql;``` and then debug it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second argument in `like` comparison array is intended to be column name by default. You should probably use expression for the whole condition, to avoid unnecessary escaping of `%`;

```
BlackListDomains::find()
    ->where(new \yii\db\Expression(":email LIKE CONCAT('%@%', domain)", [
        'email' => $email,
    ]))
    ->exists();
```

Comment: Wow, great, it works! But is it safe for SQL injection?

Comment: Yes, it is safe - it will use param binding for building this expression.